# How to change the segue type of the storyboards

Tags: xcode

I've got this problem. I want the view controller to change when the player presses a specific button.
So I added a new "view controller" in the main storyboard, I customised it and then, holding the right button of the mouse, I dragged the button on the new view controller.
It appeared a little menu with different items:

- show
- show detail
- present modally
- present as a popover
- custom

I've tried all of them, nothing changed (except for the last one: the app crashes).
The new view controller is like a moving window, if you swipe down you go back to the start menu.
What I want is that the new window replaces the first one.

Here's the problem

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the brown window is movable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you need to present view controller full screen.

You need to select "present modally" segue type. Then select segue in storyboard

[image: Storyboard segue selection]

And then select presentation style "Full screen"

[image]

Or you can make this programmatically:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let nextVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextVC") as! NextVCClass
nextVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(nextVC, animated: true)
```